# TD width not changing CSS HTML

Tags: html, css, html-table, tablecolumn

I have a table, first row 4 items (one tr, 4 td's), second row 1 item (another tr, 1 td)

I want the second row item to align center, so I want the td on the bottom row to be width 100% to fill the tr, but it is not working. Here is my current code:

```
<table style="width:100%;">
<tbody><tr>
<td style="padding:20px 5px 5px 5px; text-align:center;">
<div style="height:75px; width:75px; border-color:#8AAEA4; border-style:solid; border-width:2px; display: block; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;">
<img height="75px" width="75px" src="/images/icons/default.jpg"></div><form style="display:inline; margin:0; padding:0; " action="/dashboard/shop_window/" method="post" onsubmit="return confirm('Are you sure?');">
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="tcd.profile.delete.shop.window.item">
<input type="hidden" name="item_id" value="">
<input class="add_to_sw" style="cursor: pointer; cursor: hand; background-color:#FFF;" type="submit" value="Delete">
</form>
</td>
<td style="padding:20px 5px 5px 5px; text-align:center;">
<div style="height:75px; width:75px; border-color:#8AAEA4; border-style:solid; border-width:2px; display: block; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;">
<img height="75px" width="75px" src="/images/icons/default.jpg"></div><form style="display:inline; margin:0; padding:0; " action="/dashboard/shop_window/" method="post" onsubmit="return confirm('Are you sure?');">
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="tcd.profile.delete.shop.window.item">
<input type="hidden" name="item_id" value="">
<input class="add_to_sw" style="cursor: pointer; cursor: hand; background-color:#FFF;" type="submit" value="Delete">
</form>
</td>
<td style="padding:20px 5px 5px 5px; text-align:center;">
<div style="height:75px; width:75px; border-color:#8AAEA4; border-style:solid; border-width:2px; display: block; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;">
<img height="75px" width="75px" src="/images/icons/default.jpg"></div><form style="display:inline; margin:0; padding:0; " action="/dashboard/shop_window/" method="post" onsubmit="return confirm('Are you sure?');">
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="tcd.profile.delete.shop.window.item">
<input type="hidden" name="item_id" value="">
<input class="add_to_sw" style="cursor: pointer; cursor: hand; background-color:#FFF;" type="submit" value="Delete">
</form>
</td>

<td style="padding:20px 5px 5px 5px; text-align:center;">
<div style="height:75px; width:75px; border-color:#8AAEA4; border-style:solid; border-width:2px; display: block; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;">
<img height="75px" width="75px" src="/images/icons/default.jpg"></div><form style="display:inline; margin:0; padding:0; " action="/dashboard/shop_window/" method="post" onsubmit="return confirm('Are you sure?');">
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="tcd.profile.delete.shop.window.item">
<input type="hidden" name="item_id" value="">
<input class="add_to_sw" style="cursor: pointer; cursor: hand; background-color:#FFF;" type="submit" value="Delete">
</form>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="background-color: #FF0000; width:inherit; padding:10px 5px 5px 5px; text-align:center;">
<div style="height:75px; width:75px; border-color:#8AAEA4; border-style:solid; border-width:2px; display: block; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;">
<img height="75px" width="75px" src="/images/icons/default.jpg"></div><form style="display:inline; margin:0; padding:0; " action="/dashboard/shop_window/" method="post" onsubmit="return confirm('Are you sure?');">
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="tcd.profile.delete.shop.window.item">
<input type="hidden" name="item_id" value="">
<input class="add_to_sw" style="cursor: pointer; cursor: hand; background-color:#FFF;" type="submit" value="Delete">
</form></td>    
</tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Here is the jsfiddle: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/UqPXw/)

Comment: add a colspan as suggested by others, http://jsfiddle.net/UqPXw/2/

Comment: This is not an appropriate use of tables.  Yes, your data is tabular, but it should be expressed as one record per row, not one record per cell.

Comment: How to reformat a table:  http://codepen.io/cimmanon/pen/qCrcu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `colspan="4"` to that last `td`:

```
<td colspan="4" style="background-color: #FF0000; width:inherit; padding:10px 5px 5px 5px; text-align:center;">
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest method will be to add `colspan` property/attribute to the `td` tag. Like this:

```
<td style="background-color: #FF0000; width:inherit; padding:10px 5px 5px 5px; text-align:center;" colspan="4">
```

[Updated](http://jsfiddle.net/UqPXw/1/) fiddle link.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, colspan will only solve at a certain time. If you put another item in the second line, you'll need to use colspan="2" on the second line for two cells.

A good solution is to use div, span and css insted of table.